# Unable to compile after adding package SpecFlow.NUnit.Runner

Tags: .net, nunit, specflow

I just created a blank "Unit test project" and tried to add the nugget package "SpecFlow.NUnit.Runners".

It adds me some files(app.config, packages.config and `SpecFlowNUnitExtension`). but I'm unable to build it:

It doesn't find most of the NUNIT stuff, within `SpecFlowNUnitExtension`:
NUnit.Core, NUnit.Core.Extensibility, ...

For me it looks like when you don't have the same version of .Net between two packages. Is a specific version of .net required?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using NUnit 3.
Have a look at following issue: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/648

If you do not use the AfterTestRun hook, you can remove the file.